# Selenium JS set_preference

Tags: selenium, firefox, mime

I need to have selenium automation download a file using firefox.
The automation successfully clicks the download, but a MIME opens to ask what to do. I need selenium to ignore this and just download the file.

Everything I have read days I should be able to use a function like this

```
const firefoxOption = new firefox.Options().set_preference(
 'browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk',
 'application/zip,text/csv,text/txt',
);
```

But when I run this, it fails before it ever gets to clicking the download because this piece throws an error.

```
TypeError: (intermediate value).set_preference is not a function
```

what am I doing wrong??

ALL answers listed on SO show this exact code snippet and it is not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
const firefoxOption = new firefox.Options().setPreference(
 'browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk',
 'application/zip,text/csv,text/txt',
);
```

That method is for python

https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/javascript/module/selenium-webdriver/firefox_exports_Options.html